# Is this anchor set up right?

Tags: safety, climbing, climbing-anchors

I was just looking at an article about an expedition on Eiger.

I came across this picture.

[image]

Is this setup right?

For more info on the expedition: http://www.markseaton.com/stories/eiger.htm
Kudos to the team :)

Comment: Being the second UK guided team to climb the eiger NF is actually a thing? :P I know quite a few "unguided" teams who made the ascent... Still kudos from me too, 3 bivis on this mountain is far from comfortable.

Comment: You have also got to ask yourself, did they have any choice. A crappy anchor is better than no anchor sometimes

Comment: you have got to ask yourself about the use of wire biners on the wires. They obviously have screwgates, if your going to cross load something better to cross load a screwgate than a wire biner.

Comment: That might be true for the issue pointed out by the leftmost arrow, as it might be placement dependent, but with the gear shown in the picture, a much better solution without the other two problems could have been built.

Comment: Looks more like someond wss just hanging a pile of mostly non-safety equipment on the rock during a rest stop.

Comment: This is a keyhole view of both the anchor and the situation. We don't know what's outside the frame of the picture. We don't know what happened before or after this in time. We can't tell what the three lockers are being used for. We can't tell whether this anchor is being used for hanging packs off of or for a belay. We don't know if the person who built this had all this gear available, or if they were almost out of gear, and then the rest of the team then showed up and handed the leader a bunch of lockers, etc.

Comment: Maybe consider making your question's title more specific

Comment: @Chris: Though I agree with what Ben said above, I don't have any additional info/context to share about this one.

Comment: The narrative includes the lines _"At one point half our belay failed and the sacks set off down the mountain, threatening to take us with them.  Fortunately the remaining protection held firm.  But, from then on, a couple of tiny rock wires was all that kept the two of us and all our equipment ‘in situ’."_  Unknown is whether this was a 'before' picture or an 'after' picture.

Comment: Not sure if this is a serious question but you might enjoy this websites collection of [terrible anchors](http://jive-assanchors.com/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I couldn't have come up with a better example of "how carabiners should *never* be used" if I tried!

In fact, the most likely explanation for that picture is either such a deliberate bad example, or a joke.

A quite likely incomplete list:

- Use of non-locking carabiners in an anchor - rightmost arrow shows a nut wire just waiting to slip through a wire gate
- cross-loading, so much cross-loading! The middle arrow shows the most egregious instance - crossloading straight across a wire gate. That drastically reduces the strength.
- metal on metal in a veritable daisy chain pattern (at the bottom there is a carabiner clipped into a carabiner, which itself is clipped into two other carabiners. This stuff can too easily lever itself open (or broken).
- The whole thing is a complete mess, visually as well as technically, increasing the chance for anyone who adds or removes equipment to do make dangerous mistakes.
- The sling going to the left (left arrow) indicates that the thing is loaded sideways as well as downwards - paving the way for those nuts to wiggle themselves loose.
- One of the screwgate carabiners isn't locked. From the picture it can't be seen whether it actually serves any (critical) purpose, but if in doubt it should be closed properly.

Comment: I agree but it may be more helpful to describe what is wrong with the set up so people can learn.

Comment: I added the fact that one of the lockers isn't actually locked. I hope you agree with the edit!

Answer (score 13):

If it is load bearing, then hell no. This is a mess of cross- and ring-loading, which will break the biners.
If it is just a material storage placement, then it is simply confusing. And of what I know about the Eiger, when you find a good placement, you will never ever only use it for hanging up your gear, always for protection.
So all in all more information about the context would be needed to make a definitive answer, but I cannot imagine why this should be legit.

Edit: Unfortunately the pictures in the link given in the question are probably not in chronological order, so there is no information extractable about when or where this photo was taken.